# Cant add date more than 2 columns

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, spservices

I cant seem to add an item in more than 2 columns.
I have 3 columns, Employee ID, Employee Name, and Employee Email.

I can add in the Employee ID and the Name, but when adding the email it does not add. No error message too. Please Help.

```
function register(){

     var values = [];

     values.push(["EmployeeNumber",  $("#tbEmployeeID").val()]); 
     values.push(["EmployeeName", $("#tbEmployeeName").val()]);   
     values.push(["EmployeeEmail",$("#tbEmployeeEmail").val()]);


    $(function(){
        $().SPServices({
                        operation: "UpdateListItems",
                        async: false,
                        listName: "sampleList",
                        batchCmd: "New",
                        valuepairs: values,
                        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                            alert("Completed");
                        }
            });    
});
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There have to be commas between the value pairs:

```
[
  ["EmployeeNumber",  $("#tbEmployeeID").val()],
  ["EmployeeName", $("#tbEmployeeName").val()],
  ["EmployeeEmail",$("#tbEmployeeEmail").val()]
]
```

Comment: values.push has the same effect. Pushing the array will automatically give it commas. I also tried your code and it still doesnt work

Comment: What's the output from `$("#tbEmployeeEmail").val()`? It has to be entered as a person field. For example `["EmployeeEmail","23;#John Smith"]`

Comment: Yup I see now.. the problem was not the array. it was the data type of the entry.. Employee Email outputs Person or Groups.. Same goes for the date I guess. The date also dont enter. But I added another column which is a single line and it works. Any advice on how to enter a person or group and date?

Comment: Date has to be (off the top of my head) `2016-05-04T09:21:00Z`